# OpenLayers - Get Lat/Lon on point move

Tags: openlayers

I am very new to OpenLayers, been using Google Maps for awhile but want to switch to something more open. From examples I have seen online and responses to other questions I've seen on here I've come up with this basic map with a point: http://pastie.org/3625219

I would like to get the latitude/longitude of the point after I move it. The issue I am having is converting the projection back to 4326 from 900913. Everything I've tried for a transform comes back as blank...

SO! I am sure I am missing something basic... Javascript isn't my native language. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't need to transform x and y coordinates separately. You should make clone of feature or feature's geometry and transform geomety. For example:

```
point_transformed = feature.clone().geometry.transform(epsg900913, epsg4326);
```

See code [here](http://pastie.org/3626508).

Answer (score 0):

@scottB examine this code that shows how to identify the correct transformations for each layer.  a projection that works on openlayers might not automatically work with openstreetmaps (which is a mercator spherical projection).

i adapted  [this example from openlayers](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/mouse-position.html) so that i could accomplish 2 things:

1. save latitude and longitude of marker position
2. place a marker by clicking on the openlayers map

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" debug="true">
     <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
       <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
       <title>MousePosition Control</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/dev/theme/default/style.css" type="text/css">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/style.css" type="text/css">
       <script src="../OpenLayers.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
           var map;
           function init(){
               var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
               var proj4326 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
               var projmerc = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");
               var layerOSM = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("Street Map");
               map.addLayers([layerOSM]);
               if (!map.getCenter()) map.zoomToMaxExtent();
               map.events.register("mousemove", map, function(e) { 
                   var position = this.events.getMousePosition(e);
                   OpenLayers.Util.getElement("coords").innerHTML = 'MOUSE POSITION '+position;
                   var lonlat = map.getLonLatFromPixel( this.events.getMousePosition(e) );
                   OpenLayers.Util.getElement("lonlatTG").innerHTML = 'lonlat => '+lonlat;
                   var lonlatTransf = lonlat.transform(map.getProjectionObject(), proj4326);
                   OpenLayers.Util.getElement("lonlatTrans").innerHTML = 'lonlatTransf => '+lonlatTransf;
                   OpenLayers.Util.getElement("lonlatDouble").innerHTML = 'lonlat => '+lonlat;
               });

               map.events.register("click", map, function(e) {
                   var position = this.events.getMousePosition(e);
                   var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-pushpin.png');   
                   var lonlat = map.getLonLatFromPixel(position);
                   var lonlatTransf = lonlat.transform(map.getProjectionObject(), proj4326);
                   alert ('lonlatTrans=> lat='+lonlatTransf.lat+' lon='+lonlatTransf.lon+'\nlonlat=>'+lonlat+'\nposition=>'+position);
                   var lonlat = lonlatTransf.transform(proj4326, map.getProjectionObject());
                   var markerslayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
                   markerslayer.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(lonlat, icon));
                   map.addLayer(markerslayer);
               });
               map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
           }
       </script>
     </head>  

     <body onload="init()">
       <h1 id="title">MousePosition Control</h1>
       <div id="tags">coordinate</div>
       <p>Click on map and create marker</p>
       <div id="map" class="smallmap"></div>
       <div id="coords"></div>
       <div id="lonlatTG"></div>
       <div id="lonlatTrans"></div><br/>
       <p>
       see how, even though we did NOT transform [lonlat],
       <br/>it was nevertheless transformed
       </p>
       <div id="lonlatDouble"></div>

     </body>
   </html>
   ```

there is something that you need to be aware of regarding the TRANSFORM method for LonLat as used in this simple example: when you apply [    .transform(projection1, projection2)   ] to any LonLat, ALL LonLat objects are transformed.

play around with the order of certain commands and you will see what i mean.